# SSMA console for Access: load only certain objects?

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi

All,

I am using the SSMA console to migrate certain objects from an Access DB to SQL Server.

By default, the console LOADS all objects, but in fact I do not require all of them to be loaded, nor do they need to be converted and migrated.

I was wondering if it's possible to load only certain objects from a database instead of the entire database? If so, how can this be achieved?

I cannot find it in the documentation :(

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313064%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply expand the metadata explorer, and expand the database down to the table level. As the follow screen shot shows, you can select any table you choose.

[image]

Thus save the project, and use that as the project name when you up-size. I not looked at command line options, but specifying the project in question likly is an opiton if you not using the above GUI. So use the GUI to setup the project and select the tables you wish. You then use this project for the up-size.

Comment: Hi Thanks Albert for your reply. However, in the approach you suggest you have already loaded all objects and their meta data. When using the console, this step cannot be eliminated as far as I know..

Comment: A quick glance suggests that from the command line, it is “difficult” to use just the tables specified from the GUI. (I not done this, so I take the comments that is difficult at face value).

However, if you already done a migration, then would not the tables etc. already exist on SQL server? From that point onwards, running some “append” quires from Access to send up additional data perhaps would be an option?